# There is an error when I add ruby SDK for my project in rubymine

Tags: rubymine

At the beginning, I opened my project by rubymine. it remind me `No ruby interpreter configured for the project`. the following error emits when I add the SDK for the project following the wizard.

```
12:55:57 PM Unknown Module Type
            Cannot determine module type ("JAVA_MODULE") for the following module:"p4ep"
            The module will be treated as a Unknown module.
```

Anyone knows that's why?

Answer (score 9):

The error may occur as a result of opening the project in different IDEs.
To fix it you need to replace "JAVA_MODULE" in iml config file **.idea/project_name.iml** to "RUBY_MODULE"

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the path .idea and restart ruby project. It works for me